# Android first row with checkbox and the rest without

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have a listview with 4 rows. I'd like that the first row has a checkbox
but the other rows just keep plain clickable rows. Is this possible to do or do I need to 
create 2 listviews and put them underneath each other and make the first listview with a custom adapter?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Summary: I'd like to have a listview with the first row to be clicked and that checkbox changes states
and the other rows just keep acting as rows. Best way to do this by making 2 listview 1 with custom view and a normal one? Or is it possible to do this in 1 listview?

Comment: Set it as header view for list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your custom adapter. In `getView()` method check

```
if(position == 0)
{
    //add your checkbox
}
else
{
    //without checkbox
}
```

Comment: See this answer, should be pretty effective and simple.

Comment: This doesn't work for a `CursorAdapter`.  I think because CursorAdapter tries to be more efficient by pulling only groups of data at a time, rather than everything like an `ArrayAdapter` would do.